# Правильное построение предложения со словом "который"

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзные-слова

Правильно ли построено предложение:

Одноручный меч с прямым клинком тëмно-зелëного цвета, при дневном свете ярко переливается салатовыми бликами.

Необходимо ли перед "при дневном свете" ставить "который"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Одноручный меч **с прямым клинком тëмно-зелëного цвета**, при дневном свете **(он)** ярко переливается салатовыми бликами.*

Если это **описание** предмета, то слово "который" будет лишним.

В этом случае предложение можно отнести к БСП (бессоюзному сложному предложению): первая часть – это **назывное** предложение с определением, а вторая часть – **неполное двусоставное** предложение с пропущенным подлежащим.